# Can I created a DEM or digital surface model with high resolution image

Tags: dem, elevation, terrain, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I have VHR imagery, 5 cm pixel, and I want to create a DEM but this image has high trees and when I take my model I cant take a real elevation because DEM is not the height of the terrain.

Could I eliminate this effect?

Comment: If your images are captured from a drone and meet some requirements (e.g., overlap between one shot and the adjacents), you can build a 3D model and a DEM. Algorithms exist to classify the point cloud from which the 3D model and the DEM are based, in order discriminate between ground and off ground points. The latter can be removed and the elevation of the resulting ‘holes’ can be interpolated; but the results would not be that precise however.

Comment: If you can convert/export your elevations as LAS I would suggest LASTools LASGround https://rapidlasso.com/lastools/lasground/ to classify ground/nonground then LAS2LAS https://rapidlasso.com/lastools/las2dem/ with -keep_class 2 switch to generate a ground level DEM if at all possible among your trees... if the drone can't *see* the ground it can't *map* the ground!

Comment: Similar that Agisoft interpolation. Can you said me, one example the algorithm exist for classification. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really enough information in your question.

If you have many overlapping images you can use something like [Pix4D](https://pix4d.com/) to generate a 3D model of some form and an orthoimage using structure from motion algorithms. But, unlike LiDAR, this will not be classified.

As far as I know, you can't automatically remove trees and buildings from a 3D model generated from this kind of algorithm. Plus, imagery does not see through trees as LiDAR can (to some extent). So, you'll probably end up with a model that has lots of canopy and very little ground, depending on what the tree cover is like.

Your question does suggest you already have a DEM, and so perhaps you could try classifying the dataset to identify areas that are ground, and then exclude other areas and interpolate a new model based on that, but it's not something that is standard.

Comment: Thanks for you answers, i want classified my LAS point, and I was created a DEM, and I was overlapping my las date.